# Como borro los archivos de mas de 1mb de todos los usuarios del equipo? Windows 10

Tags: windows, script, batch, archivo

quisiera borrar todos los archivos de las carpetas Escritorio Documentos y Descargas de TODOS los usuarios del equipo que se alojan en "C:\Users".Hasta ahora he conseguido con el script de abajo pueda borrar estos archivos superiores a 1MB del usuario que introduzco. Pero quiero eliminarlos de forma automatica sin tener que meterlos todos uno por uno. Alguna de idea de como hacerlo?

```
cls
@echo PROGRMA PARA ELIMINAR FICHEROS AUTOMATICAMENTE
@echo off
@echo
@echo Se eliminaran los archivos superiores a 1mb de las carpetas Escitorio, Documentos y Descargas

set /p id=Introduzca el nombre de usuario:
@echo ESCRITORIO
forfiles /P \Users\%id%\Desktop /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize GEQ 100000 del @path"
@echo DOCUMENTOS
forfiles /P \Users\%id%\Documents /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize GEQ 1000000 del @path"
@echo DESCARGAS
forfiles /P \Users\%id%\downloads /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize GEQ 1000000 del @path"
pause
cls
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el comando `del` para su eliminación permanente de los directorios especificados, por ejemplo, la forma más común de hacerlo es `del /S /F /Q` (borrar los archivos de forma silenciosa, es decir, sin preguntar si desea borrarlos o no en los directorios).

Comment: El OP comenta "Eso no es lo que busco.. Necesito poder eliminar estos archivos de todos los usuarios, no de los que introduzco manualmente.".